# configure phpmyadmin using nginx, access phpmyadmin remotely

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, localhost, vps, appdomain

I have a remote vps server and I would like to be able to access phpmyadmin remotely because on localhost I do not have access because the server is remote, the server is a linux: Linux xddos 5.15.0-91-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 14 13:30:08 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I tried the gpt4 and bard methods, including the methods on digital oacean, but I couldn't access phpmyadmin remotely and youtube doesn't help me at all because no one talks about the problem, they all have everything on localhost, I don't understand why it's so difficult on nginx to configure this

Comment: There are ways to access the database on a remote VPS without installing extra software on the VPS.  It is the recommended approach [to not install phpMyAdmin and to use proper client-side software instead](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin).